# I have been staring at this SQL code for hours and cannot see the problem probably just being dumb (Microsoft Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

My code was working yesterday and I opened it up today and it now doesn't work. Maybe I accidentally added in an extra space. I have been through the code several times but cannot see the error. Another perspective would be very much appreciated.

```
SELECT [Student data].[Student First Name], [Student data].[Student Last Name], Guardian.[Guardian First Name], Guardian.[Guardian Last Name], Guardian.[Phone number], Form.[Form group], Medication.[Medication Name] 

FROM Form, [Student data], Guardian, Medication, [Student + Guardian], [Student + Medication] 

WHERE (Form.[Form group] = [Student data].[Form group]) AND ([Guardian].[Guardian ID] = [Student + Guardian].[Guardian ID]) AND ([Student data].[Student ID] = [Student + Guardian].[Student ID]) AND ([Medication].[Medication ID] = [Student + Medication].[Medication ID]) AND ([Student data].[Student ID] = [Student + Medication].[Student ID]) AND ([Student data].[Severity]= 'High') AND ([Student data].[Severity] = 'Moderate') AND ([Student data].[Severity]= 'Low');
```

Yesterday the table showed exactly how it was supposed to however today it will only show the names of the fields.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my teacher told me to do it that way thats why I did.

Comment: @MaryOak . . . It is very sad that anyone would be teaching that in 2020.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry. It worked previously.

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
([Student data].[Severity]= 'High') AND ([Student data].[Severity] = 'Moderate') AND ([Student data].[Severity]= 'Low')
```

will return nothing.
Change all `AND`s to `OR`s, or better use the `IN` operator:

```
[Student data].[Severity] IN ('High', 'Moderate', 'Low')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT [Student data].[Student First Name], [Student data].[Student Last Name], 
Guardian.[Guardian First Name], Guardian.[Guardian Last Name], 
Guardian.[Phone number], Form.[Form group], Medication.[Medication Name] 
FROM 
((((Form INNER JOIN [Student data] ON Form.[Form group] = [Student data].[Form group]) 
INNER JOIN [Student + Guardian] ON [Student data].[Student ID] = [Student + Guardian].[Student ID]) 
INNER JOIN [Student + Medication] ON [Student data].[Student ID] = [Student + Medication].[Student ID]) 
INNER JOIN Medication ON [Student + Medication].[Medication ID] = Medication.[Medication ID]) 
INNER JOIN Guardian ON [Student + Guardian].[Guardian ID] = Guardian.[Guardian ID]
WHERE  
[Student data].[Severity] IN ('High', 'Moderate', 'Low');
```

Here is a tip:
Use visual query designer in Access to generate the correct query just by clicking the mouse.